# Playwright Webkit encountered an internal error

Tags: automated-testing, playwright

I installed playwright using `npm init playwright@latest`
then I ran `npx playwright test`
but I got this error:

```
 1) [webkit] › example.spec.js:4:1 › has title ────────────────────────────────────────────────

    Error: page.goto: WebKit encountered an internal error
```

```
  2 failed
    [webkit] › example.spec.js:4:1 › has title ─────────────────────────────────────────────────
    [webkit] › example.spec.js:11:1 › get started link ─────────────────────────────────────────
  4 passed (18.8s)
```

Firefox and Chrome work well, but Webkit doesn't.
How can I solve this problem? I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 vscode terminal.